# How to keep focus on dropdown and having option open?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm working with this **multiselect** and I'm trying to add **focus** on dropdown while having options open (please see attached picture to see what I'm trying to accomplish).

So far when I click on dropdown I only see the options but the focus from dropdown goes away. How can I keep focus on dropdown as well as having options open?

I'm trying to accomplish this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="registrationStatus" [defaultLabel]="someText" [showHeader]="false"></p-multiSelect>
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-ubpg2x?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: So you mean you want it `yellow` backgrounded rather than default `blue` backgrounded ?

Comment: @selemmn I mean having the blue focus border on the dropdown and be able to select an option from dropdown at the same time, just like I have it on my image. Thank you

Comment: do you just want the focus style or actually focused?

Comment: I do not really get it, since there is already a blue border in the default behavior, and it doesnt go away while reopening the dropdown. I mean, you want to switch blue by yellow ? is that what you'd intended to say. sorry ..

Comment: @ABOS I want it to be actually focus. Thanks

Comment: You want customize this or go for other option because angular material is give you something like you want

Comment: @selemmn in my image I'm forcing it to be focus by opening the options and somehow clicking on the dropdown and focus on the dropdown. What I want is to click on the dropdown and then the dropdown should get focus at the same time. Hope that make sense :). Thank you

Comment: @Abhishek I don't want to use Angular material. I'm using primeNg. Thank you

Comment: Yes I misunderstand you , thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elem = (document.querySelector('.ui-multiselect') as any);
  this.elem.setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
}
```

demo 
      https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-nvwonk

you can add keyboard event etc.

Comment: How would you remove focus on blur? Thank you

Comment: register a callback for @HostListener('document:click') , and call blur.

Comment: can you update your answer with that please? Thank you

Comment: p-multiSelect has onBlur event 

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-mwcmg3 with minor issue hiding the dropdown, but should be easy fix :)

Comment: @ABOS One issue that I'm having is that I cannot longer focus on any other field, basically if I try to click on name field it automatically focuses on the dropdown, Any ideas how to fix that?. Please see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-input-multiselect-ubpg2x?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

`overlayVisible` property of `p-multiSelect` component will give a true/false value when the option panel is visable or hidden

template

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="registrationStatus" 
               [defaultLabel]="someText" [showHeader]="false" 
               #p [ngClass]="{'focus':p.overlayVisible}">
</p-multiSelect>
```

style.css

```
.focus  .ui-dropdown, .focus  .ui-multiselect {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #1f89ce;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #1f89ce;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #1f89ce;
}
```

this component has some event like `onChange , onFocus , onBlur , onPanelShow , onPanelHide` will trige base on set of action so you can trigger some event like blur , or onPanelHide after this componnt lost focus (press tab)

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53672135)

Comment: check the demo 

Comment: Your answer doesn't work. You are only styling it. I actually want it to be focused so then I can use (key.enter) and make an API call.

Comment: what you is some how not right these are list of event of `onChange , onFocus , onBlur , onPanelShow , onPanelHide` so the key press is not possible maybe onPanelHide is good fro your case

Comment: primeng 7 - key.enter on option the for select  hope this will help